# How to run puppet/systemctl inside docker container centos7

Tags: docker, puppet

My question revolves around the following problem/error.

Service/Service[jenkins]: Provider redhat is not functional on this host. OR directly that D-BUS not available.

Let's say for instance i'm running packer, which invokes a puppet-masterless provisioner on a docker builder.

The puppet code base & contrib modules for the most part will attempt to manage the 'service' of the installed module. For instance, lets take Jenkins as an example. Jenkins puppet module although good, will fail, on packer builds to a centos7 & puppet docker host. As systemctl will not be available.

At this moment in time i'm confused how this would/will ever work for puppet/ansible code bases which attempt to manage the service. Without considerable extra effort to the codebase.

I have considered the contain running being /sbin/init but still feels a bit hacky.

Can anyone shed any light on this issue for me?

Answer (score 0):

I am using ansible code to provision real machines or docker containers - to get away with SystemD / D-Bus I have created the [docker-systemctl-replacement](https://github.com/gdraheim/docker-systemctl-replacement)